# Windows Batch File that zips files from ftp location?

Tags: windows, backup, 7-zip, batch-file, xbox360

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What kind of window's batch file allows zipping of ftp files?](https://superuser.com/questions/349949/what-kind-of-windows-batch-file-allows-zipping-of-ftp-files)

Basically I want to keep backups of my xbmc files on my xbox, that is on the home network.

I already have a program (Cobian Backup) to on a schedule to ftp, copy files and zip and date them.

All this program does is just this 1 task. i have another program (System Scheduler) that I have a lot of scheduled tasks but can't handle ftping.

If I can get help creating a batch file to replace using Cobian Backup, and then schedule that batch file with my System Scheduler, then I can just uninstall cobian backup, and just run the batch file every so oftne.

Any suggestions, examples or guidelines?

Just to be clear, here is what I want the batch file to do:

1. FTP into my xbox, and go to the xbmc folder
2. Copy all that into some temporary folder that is empty.
3. Zip that up with a file name of xbmc_month_day_year.zip
4. Move that zip file to my xbox backup folder

Does that make sense?

Thank you very much.

1. Cobian Backup 10 - http://www.educ.umu.se/~cobian/cobianbackup.htm
2. System Scheduler - http://www.splinterware.com/products/wincron.htm

Comment: out of curiousity, what is "System Scheduled" ? nothing comes up on google, is it a typo?

Comment: being familiar with xp, I see xp has "scheduled tasks".

Comment: Yes it does, but these programs are much more flexible, and have many more options.

Comment: Can't you disable Cobian's schedule function and manually run it from System Scheduler?

Comment: My question was simple, give me a batch file that can zip up files via ftp location. Why is this hard to understand? Cobian Backup does the zip and ftp itself, which is why I would prefer to just have a batch file do it.

Comment: Created a far dumbed down version of this question. http://superuser.com/questions/349949/what-kind-of-windows-batch-file-allows-zipping-of-ftp-files